# New to the world of Bitcoin

Tags: transactions

I'm an amateur who's yet to dive into the game of cryptocurrency. I've never even played around in stock markets. Ok so the price of Bitcoin fluctuates, and you can do things like buy, sell, trade, wire transfer, and even cash out. But here's my question.

Can I walk away from the table temporarily and come back in at a later time or date? I'm a guy that likes to pick his spots, sort of speak. Can you pull in and pull out as you wish? Or are my options only to remain on the table, buy, sell, trade our cash out?

I wouldn't want to have to buy back in at a higher price.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I walk away from the table temporarily and come back in at a later time or date?

Sure you can.

It isn't a perfect analogy, but think about bitcoin as if it were a dollar bill in your pocket. Some people will obtain a dollar bill, and then stash it away in a safe, not touching it for years. Others will take that dollar bill straight to the casino, keeping it on the table to bet and play with.

There is no requirement to continuously buy/sell, bitcoin is not some sort of game. It is just an asset you can own, and do with as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. People in the Bitcoin community I notice are very helpful and generous. So since I can get in on the "live action" as I please.. what exactly is the proper term I'd be looking for in my account to "pause or freeze" my involvement temporarily?

Comment: Happy to help. I think you misunderstand what is involved though, it isn’t as if bitcoin is a game where you plug in/out of the live action. To own bitcoin, you’ll need a wallet of some sort, there are several types. You’ll need to choose one that suits your needs best, and transfer the bitcoins you purchase to an address from that wallet. For long term storage I would recommend looking at hardware wallets.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah I guess everyone would be doing the same thing if it was that simple and easy to hit a "pause button" when the numbers decline while you wait for them to soar back up again. I'm an old fart lol. I have heard about those things like "virtual wallets", cold storage  flash keys, and paper wallets.. so I see what you're saying. Find something that suits my needs. Thanks again chytrik. Cheers!